# Bayonetta 1 quicktime events show wrong controller on Wii U

Tags: wii-u, bayonetta

I'm playing through level 1 and am at the part where you have to jump off a bridge as it is being thrown. During this quicktime event, I'm shown what action I have to perform on the gamepad. However, I'm playing using the pro controller with the gamepad nowhere near me.

I finished this level two days ago, also using only the pro controller, and I didn't have to use the gamepad at that time. I tried restarting the level, the game, and even the wii u itself but nothing seems to convince Bayonetta that I'm not using the gamepad. I just keep dying no matter what button I press and it is rather annoying. Even if I perform the specified action on the gamepad during the quicktime event it doesn't work.

Does anyone know what's going on and what I should do?

Answer (score -1):

Well.. feeling rather stupid now. I was supposed to jump while pressing the left stick forward, whereas I was only trying jump or stick forward separately. The fact that the quicktime event shows a gamepad makes no difference for what controller I can use there.